# Where can I read Mahou to Skytube de Ikiteiku?

Tags: resources, mahou-to-skytube-de-ikiteiku

I found *Mahou to Skytube de Ikiteiku* by accident at some point not that long ago and tried to look for it everywhere, even on illegal websites (though I'd much prefer a physical copy). However, I can't seem to find much about it.

Where can I legally obtain a physical copy, or failing that, where can I legally read it online?

Comment: Welcome to Anime.SE! Please note that this site does not endorse piracy, so we cannot and will not link you to any illegal sites.

Comment: Looks like there's only a light novel, not a manga adaptation. Also, looks like it hasn't been licensed (and has a low potential, since it finished in only 1 volume), so there's no official English version, only the original Japanese language (魔法とSkyTubeで生きていく).